# How does a concave lens form a virtual image?

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction

If rays of light are diverged upon exiting a concave lens, then they have no focal point. The rays completely spread out in random directions. Like diffuse reflection(which does not form an image)

So how can concave lenses produce virtual images?

Comment: Can you contrast with an optical system where you *do* understand how a virtual image is formed? A good starting point would be a plane or curved mirror.  Note that if you believe the directions of the refracted light rays are "random," that is part of your trouble.

Comment: Using Snell's Law and the Law of Reflection you can sort out the direction light beams go after passing into and out of a lens. The smooth boundaries of the lens remove the randomness from the direction allowing for the creation of a virtual image.